# Having some trouble retrieving information from JToggleButton?(Matching Game)

Tags: java, arrays, swing, actionlistener

I am currently trying to program a memory/matching game. I am having a problem with trying to figure out how to check if the same card has been clicked and the user found a match. I understand that I need to store the value of the first click and compare it to the second click but still unsure about how to actually do it.

Consider this code, i have recreated a more simple version of the game which you can actually run below:

```
class start {

    JToggleButton DisplayCards[][] = new JToggleButton[4][4];
    Shuffle shuffle = new Shuffle();
    void main() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        int y = 20;
        int x = 60;

        for (int i = 0; i < DisplayCards.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < DisplayCards[i].length; ++j) {
                DisplayCards[i][j] = new JToggleButton("Click Me!");


                DisplayCards[i][j].setBounds(x, y, 90, 126);
                y = y + 135;
                if (y >= 540) {
                    y = 20;
                    x = x + 120;
                }
                frame.add(DisplayCards[i][j]);
                DisplayCards[i][j].addActionListener(new Clicked(i, j, shuffle));
            }
        }

        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Class to Shuffle the letters:

```
class Shuffle {

    String[][] cards = {
        {"A", "B", "C", "D"},
        {"E", "F", "G", "H"},
        {"A", "B", "C", "D"},
        {"E", "F", "G", "H"}

    };

    public void random() {
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cards[i].length; j++) {
                int i1 = (int) (Math.random() * cards.length);
                int j1 = (int) (Math.random() * cards[i].length);

                String temp = cards[i][j];
                cards[i][j] = cards[i1][j1];
                cards[i1][j1] = temp;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Class for ActionListener:

```
class Clicked implements ActionListener {

    Shuffle shuffle;
    JToggleButton tBtn;
    private int i;
    private int j;

    public Clicked(int i, int j, Shuffle shuffle) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
        this.shuffle = shuffle;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tBtn = (JToggleButton) e.getSource();
        if (tBtn.isSelected()) {
            tBtn.setText(shuffle.cards[i][j]);

        } else {
            tBtn.setText("Click Me!");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the values that are chosen and compare them.  Here is a rough example.

I called your main class `PuzzleGame`.

In the main class I put in two static values.

```
static String first;
static boolean state = false;
```

Then I modified your action listener as follows.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tBtn = (JToggleButton) e.getSource();
        if (tBtn.isSelected()) {
            tBtn.setText(shuffle.cards[i][j]);
            if (!PuzzleGame.state) {
                PuzzleGame.first = shuffle.cards[i][j];
                System.out.println(PuzzleGame.first);
                PuzzleGame.state = true;

            } else {
                if (PuzzleGame.first.equals(shuffle.cards[i][j])) {
                    System.out.println("Correct!");
                }
            }
        } else {
            tBtn.setText("Click Me!");
        }

    }
```

The first time thru, `state` is `false` so `first` is set.  The second time thru, `state` is `true` so the comparison is done to what `first` was set too.

In a game such as this you should NOT use static values.  I did it because it was easy to demonstrate the technique.

You should also reset the values and state for an incorrect answer and disable the buttons for a correct one.

One final tip.

```
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // centers the frame on screen.
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would i make the two buttons disappear if they were matched?

Comment: `setEnabled(false);`  They don't disappear, they just get greyed out and don't respond to clicks.

Comment: @JoshuaSaikali  Did you try this?  Did it work for you?